Uniform Convergence in Probability of Parameterized Functions
I want to show that
$$\text{arg} \, \text{min}_x \; f_{\hat{\theta}_n}(x) \overset{P}{\rightarrow} \text{arg} \, \text{min}_x \; f_\theta(x),$$
where $f_{\hat{\theta}_n}$ is a function that is parameterized by $\hat{\theta}_n$, which is a consistent estimator for the true $\theta$, i.e., $\hat{\theta}_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} \theta$. What are sufficient conditions, such that the claim is true? It seems that one way is to show that $f_{\hat{\theta}_n}$ is uniformly convergent in probability. How can we show this? Is there another way?
